# Using object.relatedname_set.all vs object.relatedname.all for ForeignKey in a template

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I am trying to understand the difference between using `relatedname_set.all` vs `relatedname.all`. I have a template that I was unable to get to iterate through objects via a ForeignKey with `relatedname_set.all`. I just happened to change it to `relatedname.all` and it worked. See below. I have a ListView that gives all of my Cooker objects which points to the template.

My Models

```
class Cooker(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=20, name="name")
  background = models.CharField(max_length=500, name="background")

class Formula(models.Model):
  food = models.CharField(max_length=200, name="food")
  maker = models.ForeignKey(Cooker, related_name="cooker2")
```

Template that works:

```
<body>
{% for cook in cooker_list %}
   <h2><li>{{ cook.name }}</li></h2>
   <li>{% for recipe in cook.cooker2.all %}
        {{ recipe.food }}
        {% endfor %}</li>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

Template line that does not work (4th line):

```
   <li>{% for recipe in cook.cooker2_set.all %}
```

Comment: Because you've setted a related_name on the relation, so you have to use it properly

Comment: `cooker2_set` would never work unless you had `related_name='cooker2_set'`. If you don't set `related_name`, it will default to `formula_set`. Looking at your models, I would recommend `related_name='formulas'`, since `cook.formulas.all()` give you the related `Formula` instances, not `Cooker` instances.

Comment: ok thanks, I will look through my ForeignKeys and pick some better names. I originally stayed away from using the Model name as the `related_name` because when I was first starting I was not sure if I was actually using the `related_name` or using the Model name.. Since they were both the same, but now i get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs for [be careful with `related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#be-careful-with-related-name),

> If you **don’t** specify a related_name attribute for a field in an abstract base class, the **default reverse name** will be the name of the child class followed by `'_set'`, just as it normally would be if you’d declared the field directly on the child class. For example, in the above code, if the related_name attribute was omitted, the reverse name for the m2m field would be childa_set in the ChildA case and childb_set for the ChildB field.

Essentially, by providing your own, you're overriding the default.